# how to subtract in mysql at the same row based on another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to subtract sold dollars against bought dollars.

```
**|Tran_ID|Currency_type|currency_Amount|Local_Amount|  Rate  |Tran_type| ** 
  | 85     |   USD      |   2500       |    1581.54  |1.58074 |  Bought |
  | 78     |   USD      |   3487.57    |    2206.29  |1.58074 |  Bought |
  | 86     |   USD      |   100        |    63.26    |1.58074 |  Bought |
  | 87     |   USD      |   94.17      |    63.26    |1.48866 |  Sold   |
  | 88     |   USD      |   2600       |    1746.54  |1.48866 |  Sold   |
  | 89     |   USD      |   2600       |    1746.54  |1.48866 |  Sold   |
```

I can Add the total values of dollars sold or bought with the query below

```
SELECT Currency_type, sum( currency_Amount ) AS total_bought
FROM Transaction
WHERE Currency_type=  'USD'
AND Tran_type =  'Bought'       <==  **or 'Sold'**
```

the outcome is below

```
**|Currency_type | total_bought    |**
|USD             |6087.570068359375|
```

Comment: One of those three columns (currency_Amount|Local_Amount|Rate) is redundant as each can be easily derived from the other two... oh, and your currency data type is DECIMAL, right?

Comment: yes  it is,but I am using the database to connect to frontend application, which  I am filtering it there ,

Comment: What is the question? If you want to correlate diferent rows in the database then you need a key which links these 2 rows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just can have a sign conditioned on your transaction type:

```
SUM(currency_Amount * IF(Tran_type = "Bought", 1, -1))
```

Comment: How can I minus the both values together >? for example dollars bought equal to 6087.57  and sold dollars equal 5294.16.  subtracting them give me 793.41 in balance. how could i query that ?

Comment: My answer should work. Replace your SUM with this and remove AND.